# os.Process.Wait() after os.FindProcess(pid) works on windows not on linux

Tags: linux, windows, go

I have an issue when trying to recover a process in go. My go app launch a bunch of processes and when it crashes the processes are out there in the open and when I rerun my app I want to recover my processes. On windows everything works as expected I can `wait()` on the process `kill()` it etc.. but in linux it just goes trough my `wait()` without any error. 
Here is the code

```
func (proc *process) Recover() {

    pr, err := os.FindProcess(proc.Cmd.Process.Pid)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    log.Info("Recovering " + proc.Name + proc.Service.Version)

    Processes.Lock()
    Processes.Map[proc.Name] = proc
    Processes.Unlock()
    proc.Cmd.Process = pr

    if proc.Service.Reload > 0 {
        proc.End = make(chan bool)
        go proc.KillRoutine()
    }

    proc.Cmd.Wait()

    if proc.Status != "killed" {
        proc.Status = "finished"
    }
    proc.Time = time.Now()


    channelProcess <- proc

    //confirmation that process was killed
    if proc.End != nil {
        proc.End <- true
    }

}
```

process is my own struct to handle processes the important part is cmd which is from the package `"os/exec"`  I have also tried to directly call `pr.wait()` with the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not handing the error message from `Wait`. Try:

```
ps, err := proc.Cmd.Wait()
if err != nil {
    /* handle it */
}
```

Also [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Wait) says:

> Wait waits for the Process to exit, and then returns a ProcessState
>   describing its status and an error, if any. Wait releases any
>   resources associated with the Process. **On most operating systems, the
>   Process must be a child of the current process or an error will be
>   returned**.

In your case since you're "recovering", your process is not the parent of the processes you found using `os.FindProcess`.

So why does it work on windows? I suspect it is because [on windows](https://golang.org/src/os/exec_windows.go) it boils down to [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032) which doesn't have that requirement.

Comment: Oh right I was handling the error of the proc (in another go routine) but not on the actual wait. Do you have any suggestion on how I could recover a process that is, de facto, not a child anymore?

Comment: @Lomithrani I may have a few suggestions. What are you trying to do with the process after you "recover" it? Also, anticipating my next question: if you take a few steps back: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My program manage programs (but as it is my first go program it might panic sometimes). I can see what programs are running etc.  basically I need to know if they run and be able to kill them and to know when they crash.  just monitoring processes and not running them directly means  redoing my all app from scratch.It works the way I want on windows it's quite frustrating not to be able to do the same on linux :( I thought about creating a another process to handle the processes if my app crash with PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER and give them back the same way once my app re runs

Comment: @Lomithrani I think this is not its intended use case but you might be able to use `ptrace(2)` for what you need (it will let you wait on other processes).

Comment: I will look into that, it does seem that it could work thankyou

Comment: from what I read it seems that if I attach my new process instance to the lost one with ptrace, I will send a sigstop to it. I don't want to interfere with my orphan process. Just to be able to stop it or know when it stopped. Are you sure that I can achieve this with ptrace?

Comment: @Lomithrani, send the process `SIGCONT` and it will continue from where it was `SIGSTOP`-ped. Still, I think your whole approioach is misconsieved. Why not just persist the PIDs of those processes somewhere, zap that storage on clean exit and read it after restart?

Comment: @Lomithrani, ...or, better, why not delegate monitoring these processed to the process which monitors your (crashing) Go program?  Say, with `systemd` I beleive this is the standard mode of operation: it places each daemon process into its own `cgroup` and makes sure that no matter how that process or its children procuced other children (calling `setsid()` et al notwithstanding) bringing down that daemon will bring down everything it spawned.  So it just works.

Comment: @Lomithrani, if not using `systemd`, you can study [Unix process groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) and try making a process group out of your Go program so that when it dies -- from the OS sending it a deadly signal -- that signal brings the whole process group down.